# AAPT Failing on Debian Jenkins Server Gradle Build with Build Tools 24.+

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, aapt

Build works fine on my Mac but not on the Debian Jenkins server. Only happens when running build tools 24.+. I think it is something to do with a PNG file due to it saying `Thread(png-cruncher-3): Stream closed`.

I get the following error:

```
:app:mergeDebugResourcesAAPT err(Facade for 1989818655): /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I then get caught in the following infinite loop:

```
Thread(png-cruncher_3): Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:433)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.shutdown(AaptProcess.java:143)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.destruction(QueuedCruncher.java:144)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:245)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The version of Debian I'm running is:

```
Linux f88267848086 4.4.15-moby #1 SMP Thu Jul 28 22:03:07 UTC 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**EDIT** - Added more debug logs after @Ashish's answer

```
15:29:46.069 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.changes.RebuildIncrementalTaskInputs] All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
15:29:46.075 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Unable do incremental execution: full task run
15:29:49.483 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] QueuedCruncher is using /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt
15:29:49.624 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Trying to start /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt
15:29:49.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Trying to start /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt
15:29:49.632 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Trying to start /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt
15:29:49.632 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Trying to start /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt
15:29:49.650 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(pool-3-thread-1): begin waitForAll
15:29:49.639 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Trying to start /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt
15:29:49.690 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(pool-3-thread-1) : wait for {QueuedJob{
title=Cruncher abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png, 
task={from=abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png, to=/var/jenkins_home/workspace/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/debug/drawable-hdpi-v4/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha.png}, 
latch=BooleanLatch{signaled=false}, 
result=false})
15:29:50.036 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Started 662662616
15:29:50.044 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] Thread(png-cruncher_1): created aapt slave, Process(662662616)
15:29:50.056 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] AAPT err(Facade for 2095046102): /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: 1: /var/jenkins_home/tools/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.2/aapt: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Easier thing to do will be to remove that PNG file and then run the build again. 
If that narrows down to your PNG idea. 

 However you can paste the details logs here by running gradle build with -d option.
```

see this 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html

Comment: It appears you have saved jpeg as png file.